# Insert em multiplas da tabelas

Tags: mysql

Estou querendo fazer o seguinte insert no MySql

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE cadastroLocal (var_localNome varchar(80),  var_horainicial TIME, var_horafinal TIME, var_periodoemminutos INTEGER, var_diasdasemana INTEGER)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO LOCAL (LOCAL.NOME) VALUES (var_localNome);
   SET @localid  = LAST_INSERT_ID();
   INSERT INTO HORARIO (HORARIO.HORAINICIAL, HORARIO.HORAFINAL, HORARIO.PERIODOEMMINUTOS) VALUES (var_horainicial, var_horafinal, var_periodoemminutos);
   SET @horarioid  = LAST_INSERT_ID();
   INSERT INTO CONFIGURACAODELOCAL (CONFIGURACAODELOCAL.LOCALID, CONFIGURACAODELOCAL.DIADASEMANA, HORARIO.HORARIOID) VALUES (@localid, var_diasdasemana, @horarioid);
```

Porém o seguinte erro aparece:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 3

Sendo que em nenhum lugar exite essas aspas simples. Já olhei documentação e outras perguntas que são para duas tabelas.

Alguém dá um ideia, ou até mesmo alguém sabe se isso é possível para mais de duas tables?

Comment: Acho que ele está querendo dizer que você deve utilizar as aspas simples, não é não?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema acontece por causa dos delimitadores. Você precisa mudar o delimitador (;) por um instante, para que o seu programa consiga passar o texto da procedure para o MySQL. Para mais detalhes, veja na [documentação do mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-defining.html).

Tente:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE cadastroLocal (var_localNome varchar(80),  
                                var_horainicial TIME, 
                                var_horafinal TIME, 
                                var_periodoemminutos INTEGER, 
                                var_diasdasemana INTEGER)
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO 
      LOCAL (LOCAL.NOME) 
   VALUES 
      (var_localNome);

   SET @localid  = LAST_INSERT_ID();
   INSERT INTO HORARIO (HORARIO.HORAINICIAL, HORARIO.HORAFINAL, HORARIO.PERIODOEMMINUTOS) VALUES (var_horainicial, var_horafinal, var_periodoemminutos)$$
   SET @horarioid  = LAST_INSERT_ID();
   INSERT INTO CONFIGURACAODELOCAL (CONFIGURACAODELOCAL.LOCALID, CONFIGURACAODELOCAL.DIADASEMANA, HORARIO.HORARIOID) VALUES (@localid, var_diasdasemana, @horarioid);

END

//
```

### Update

Troquei o delimitador de acordo com o sugerido pelo @Jessé.

Comment: **Nota:** A palavra `LOCAL` é reservada e não devia estar a ser utilizada como nome da tabela. De qualquer forma, o código com o `delimiter` em uso continua a dar o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente gostaria de agradecer ao apoio.

Diferente do sugerido pelo companheiro anmaia, substitui na cria o delimiter $$ pelo o do exemplo da documentação do mysql.

Logo resolvi meu problema assim:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE cadastroLocal (var_localNome varchar(80),
                                var_horainicial TIME, 
                                var_horafinal TIME,
                                var_periodoemminutos INTEGER, 
                                var_diasdasemana INTEGER)
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO 
      LOCALL (LOCALL.NOME)
   VALUES 
      (var_localNome);

   SET @localid  = LAST_INSERT_ID();
   INSERT INTO HORARIO (HORARIO.HORAINICIAL, HORARIO.HORAFINAL, HORARIO.PERIODOEMMINUTOS) VALUES (var_horainicial, var_horafinal, var_periodoemminutos);
   SET @horarioid  = LAST_INSERT_ID();
   INSERT INTO CONFIGURACAODELOCAL (CONFIGURACAODELOCAL.LOCALID, CONFIGURACAODELOCAL.DIADASEMANA, CONFIGURACAODELOCAL.HORARIOID) VALUES (@localid, var_diasdasemana, @horarioid);
END 

//
```

obrigado!

Comment: ao invés de criar uma outra resposta, comenta na resposta que lhe dei. Assim, evitaremos ao parecido com fórum.